# Citation in lecture notes?

Tags: citations, lecture-notes

We do citations when we refer to someone else’s papers but what about lecture notes? If I come across someone’s lecture notes which has a different way of presentation of a theorem or some problem and I wish to expose my students to it, how do I make use of it? Can I use the other person’s diagrams or solutions and give them the credit?

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 and other close-voters: This question is broader because it also asks about the reuse of material from the lecture notes into new notes. I don't think it can be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

There are two questions here:

- how to cite?
- can (and how) such materials be used?

The first question can be certainly answered. [Library Guides from Victoria University](http://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/apa-referencing/course-lecture-notes) has the following example in APA style:

> Ooi, D. (2018). *AEB1804: Young People in a Global Community, week 1, session 1 notes* [Course Presentation]. Retrieved from https://vucollaborate.vu.edu.au/d2l/le/content/177492/viewContent/2217850/View

[This question also deals with citing lecture notes and when to do it](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10411/56594). Concrete example [for lab manuals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/21766/56594) and [lecture notes](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/89000/56594).

[An important discussion on whether to use citations while preparing your lecture notes](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/108883/56594) can give a perspective on why doing proper citations in lecture notes is a good idea.

However, citing lecture notes has its limitations, since lecture notes are essentially [gray literature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_literature).

Now, to the second question *whether and how you can use them*, **which is a question of copyright**. [This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/93492/56594) discusses the copyright-issues-free preparation of lecture notes to get you started.

Lecture notes rarely mention a license under which they are published, so you cannot assume they are in the public domain or under a permissive license. You can contact the author of the notes (or the copyright holder, which might be university). This will raise two problems (that theoretically can be resolved):

- sometimes it is actually unclear who is a copyright holder for the lecture notes
- you rely on the fact that the lecture notes you are trying to use do not infringe copyrights on their own

---

So, I would suggest the following. Use the material from the lecture notes in a way that will constitute [**fair use**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use). Citing paragraphs here and there would certainly be fair use while using images and figures [might not be](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/40173/56594), as well as using entire chapters. Use appropriate citations where applicable. Also, consider asking the author of the notes for an explicit permission.

Known assumptions and limitations of this answer:

- you do not intend to sell your lecture notes
- copyright law is complicated and has its own peculiarities in every country
- you intend a fair use (in a common, not legal, sense) and wish to be as fair and copyright-respectful as possible

Answer (score 2):

For figures, one can include a figure credit in the caption, something as simple as “Figure credit: Zerothehero, unpublished lecture notes.”

The same holds for theorems:

Theorem: [Zerothehero, unpublished lecture notes] The Sun rises in the East.

Or

Theorem: The Sun rises in the East [see also Zerothehero, unpublished lecture notes]

You might also include a link or better yet the DOI if the lecture notes have been assigned one.